# PHP sending email from an include file

Tags: php

I'd like to create an includes file which sends an email to user when he logs in. This is how my users get authenticated:
1- my authenticate include file chooses users password in the database based on the user email the login.php passes.
2- if the user is authenticated i just create 2 session variables user_id and user_name

So what I'd like to do is, once the user is authenticated I would like to call my send_login_email function within my email_function include file. 
I'm also planning to create more email functions whereby I send an email to user for other notifications, so it's important for the user_email to be saved in a session variable.
This is what my send email includes file lookslike at the moment:

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/authenticate.inc.php');
function login_mail($_SESSION['uemail'])
{
$to = $_SESSION['uemail'];
$subject = "login";
$message = <?php $user_name ?>, You have logged in.";
$from = "example@email.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
?>
```

In my authenticate file I select user details as shown below:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT salt, user_password, user_role, user_name, person_id FROM users WHERE user_email = ?';
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
// bind the input parameter
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user_email);
// bind the result, using a new variable for the password
$stmt->bind_result($salt, $storedPwd, $user_role, $user_name, $person_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
```

and within the if statement that checks if the password is correct i have the following code-**I'm also calling the email function here**:

```
$_SESSION['start'] = time();
  session_regenerate_id();
  header("Location: $redirect");
  // get the user's name and id
  $_SESSION['name'] = $user_name;
  $_SESSION['id'] = $person_id;
  $_SESSION['uemail'] = $user_email;
  require_once('../includes/email_func.inc.php'); //new stuff
  login_mail($_SESSION['uemail']);
```

When I login sucessfully I do not receive an email.
I'm new to using functions and emails within php and Id really appreciate some help please.
Thank you

Comment: check this line: `$message = <?php $user_name ?>, You have logged in.";` I saw `<?php $user_name ?>` which doesn't look in its place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function as follows:

```
function login_mail($to, $user_name)
{
$subject = "login";
$message = "$user_name, You have logged in.";
$from = "example@email.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

Then call it as:

```
login_mail($_SESSION['uemail'], $user_name);
```

The arguments of a function must be ordinary variables, not array elements. You were trying to reference `$user_name`, which didn't exist in the function. And `<?php ...?>` is not used in ordinary assignments, it's used when switching from HTML output to PHP code.

Make sure you have error reporting enabled, you should have gotten errors from those mistakes.

Comment: thank you, this worked. Although when I called it i passed user name as $_SESSION['name']. It's all working now, thanks again